# Disable @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-integration

I wonder how I can get rid of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

The [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html) mentions that

> If you need to find out what auto-configuration is currently being
>   applied, and why, starting your application with the --debug switch

but I can't find which auto-configurations are applied in the shell.

How does it look like and **how do I import / enable just the necessary configurations** for my application?
I'm especially interested to just load the spring data autoconfiguration for fast running integration tests.

**== Update ==**

Adding

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EntityScan("persistence.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("persistence.repositories")
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@Configuration
@Import({ AopAutoConfiguration.class, AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration.class,
        AuditAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaBaseConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        JtaAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class,
        PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class,
        PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class, ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class,
        ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class, SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableIntegration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = QueryTests.class)
public class QueryTests {...
```

to my JUnit test now throws an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages` (see below).

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages.get(AutoConfigurationPackages.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getBasePackages(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE] ...
```

Comment: Can't find what in the shell? And why not just directly import the specific autoconfiguration classes you want like any other configurations?

Comment: I can't find which auto-configurations are applied in the shell.  I've tried to use @Import(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class), but without success.

Answer (score 2):

To see the Spring Boot stuff in the logs I add `--debug` to `Program Arguments` when I run that my Boot application from the IDEA. 
From command line it looks like:

```
D:\Java\jdk8\bin\java -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "[SOME CP]" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.springframework.integration.samples.dsl.cafe.lambda.Application --debug
```

With that I can see in the console something like this:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy,org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)
      - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration
      - matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration
      - Automatic cache type (CacheCondition)
```

And so on.

For you second question there are two ways:

- Disable undesired AutoConfiguration using `@SpringBootApplication(exclude)`
- Don't rely on the Boot and just import required configurations. For example:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @Import({PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class, ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class,
      EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class})
  @EnableIntegration
  public static class ContextConfiguration {
  ```

Comment: thanks for your response. Sadly, I get an IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages

Comment: From one side you really should distinguish `configuration` and `test` and don't mix everything on the test class. From other side your new issue isn't related to the original question. And it really looks like `AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport` can't live without `@EnableAutoConfiguration`... Feel free to raise GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have tried giving --debug but i am receiving as unrecognised command.

Comment: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -ea --debug -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/home/akhil-kfn/Downloads/idea-IC-191.7479.19/lib/idea_rt.jar=32827:/home/akhil-kfn/Downloads/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath <classPaths> 
 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.kaleidofin.app.unit.kra.cacheIncrementTest 

Unrecognized option: --debug
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit